# TS2322: Type '{ scale: number; }' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hook

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import {
    useAnimatedStyle,
    useSharedValue,
    withSpring
} from 'react-native-reanimated'

export const useScaleOnMount = () => {
    const scale = useSharedValue(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        scale.value = withSpring(1)

        return () => {
            scale.value = withSpring(0)
        }
    }, [])

    const styleAnimation = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
        transform: [
            {
                scale: scale.value
            }
        ]
    }))

    return { styleAnimation }}
```

ошибка

> TS2322: Type '{ scale: number; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.

не понимаю в чем ошибка, помогите пожалуйста

ошибка тут

```
{
    scale: scale.value
}
```

Comment: TS думает, что `scale.value` может вообще отсутствовать. Попробуйте типизировать переменную, как указано в [документации](https://reactnativedev.ru/community/reanimated.3/core/useSharedValue/#_1)

Comment: Попробоавал, не получилоось(

Comment: какой тип у `useSharedValue`, `withSpring`, `useAnimatedStyle`?

Answer (score 0):

По какой-то причине свойство `transform` в возвращаемом типе параметра функции `useAnimatedStyle` имеет тип `never[]`.

Скорее всего проблема в типах библиотеки `react-native-reanimated`